# Exact Match in R - Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex

I have problems with the next matching.

Suppose I have the next formula:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("make thingsdo happn", "make|thin|happn|link|space")

[1] "make"  "thin"  "happn"
```

The function is returning correctly the word "make" and "happn", but not "thin". So, I need a function which returns each word that exactly match with the list provided.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Don't forget to include your handy `library(stringr)`, which is necessary for the function. This is helpful for others if they would like to build upon this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include word boundaries `\b`...

```
str_extract_all("make thingsdo happn", "\\b(make|thin|happn|link|space)\\b")

[1] "make"  "happn"
```

Comment: Perfect!, so, to complete my formul,a if I have a data frame I can finish with: str_extract_all(table$col1, eval(paste0("\\b(",paste(words, collapse="|"),")\\b")))

Comment: Yes - although you might not need the `eval`